# Is there a way to reference a returned dataframe's variable in R without an assignment?

Tags: r, dataframe, return-value, coding-efficiency

I'm trying to see if I can do the following code using only a single assignment and one line of code in R.

This is how I wish it could work. Variable/Column names I wish to select are 'Diet' and 'Time':

```
data.melted <- melt.data.frame(ChickWeight, measure.vars = 'weight', na.rm=T)[c(Diet == 1 | Diet == 4 & Time == 21)]
```

This is how I get it to currently work:

```
data.melted <- melt.data.frame(ChickWeight, measure.vars = 'weight', na.rm=T)
data.melted <- diet.data.melted[c((data.melted$Diet == 1 | data.melted$Diet == 4) & data.melted$Time == 21),]
```

Is there a way to reference the object that get returned from a function, like a reserve word such that I could select the columns? As in:

```
melt.data.frame(ChickWeight, measure.vars = 'weight', na.rm=T)[ReserveWordForReturnedDF$Time,]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe (`%>%`) was introduced to avoid creating such intermediate objects. You can do :

```
library(magrittr)

melt.data.frame(ChickWeight, measure.vars = 'weight', na.rm=TRUE) %>%
   dplyr::filter(Diet %in% c(1, 4) & Time == 21)
```